# Storing/normalising and searching address data

Tags: java, mongodb, search, addressbook

I have a *lot* of address data linked to names.  Addresses are in multiple formats.  Examples could be:

- 1 StreetName Street, County, Town.
- 1, StreetName Street, County, Town.
- Flat 1 BuildingName, 1 StreetName Street, Town.
- Flat 1 BuildingName, StreetName Street, County, Town.
- Flat 1, 1 StreetName Street, District, Town.
- Flat 1, BuildingName, 1 StreetName Street, County, Town.

etc etc etc.  I have separate (UK) postcode data for each address and have normalised these so that case and delimiters are consistent even if the content of each "line" is not.  Inconsistent wording, like Street vs St still exists.

My approach so far has had reasonable but limited success.  I have indexed the postcodes and forced users to select postal districts, which slices the data into much smaller available chunks.  After that I'm left with using regular expression queries (I'm using mongo at the moment) over addresses to look for street names.

However, due to inconsistent wording that I can only normalise so far (example: generating "High (Street|St)" from user queries when querying or normalising at the database level) this has not been super accurate, or fast.

I realise it's a fairly open question, but how would people suggest it's made available for search and/or normalised further?  Restrictions I have to enforce on search include not being able to search by name, and not resolving to people until they are narrowed down to individual streets/roads (note that some addresses don't have street/road information!).  Note that a lot of the data is historic, so looking it up via google or whoever is not really an option.

Comment: Have you looked at something like [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)? We had a similar problem at an earlier workplace of mine, where we ended up using lucene to handle free text search, made it return just the id's of the matching records and then look up the actual data from the legacy database (huge system, replacing the database was not an option).

Comment: I'm just about to try fulltext indexing the address field and seeing how it works out.  I'm not sure what Mongo uses to do this but it wouldn't surprise me if it's lucene based (it's also a beta feature at the moment).  My worry is that text searches for things like "London Road, Bath" will return an awful lot of "London" addresses elsewhere or miss "London Rd, Bath" etc etc.  I think I will have to try it and see how it behaves in those instances.  It's also limited to 100 results per query in Mongo.  Perhaps a separate lucene index is the way to go.

Comment: I'll add that although I've currently built this on top of mongo it's a prototype, so other, more suitable data back ends are still an option.  I've also found a fantastic list of shortend address forms here that I can hopefully use to further normalise: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Name_finder:Abbreviations#English

Comment: @tom, the full text search built into mongo isn't going to do what you want it to.  It's built from the ground up(not based on lucene), and doesn't support much more than very basic searches(words, phrases, and the negation of words and phrases).  Searching "ondon" will not return documents with "London" in them.  That being said, check it out and see if it's good enough for your application.

Comment: Cheers for the info @JonathanF